# Personalized Search Results based on History

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, search

What are some of the techniques for providing personalized search results to a logged in user? One way I can think of will be by analyzing the user's browsing history.

**Tracking**: A log of a user's activities like pages viewed and 'like' buttons clicked can be use to bias search results.

***Question 1***: How do you track a user's browsing history? A table with columns `user_id`, `number_of_hits`, `page id`? If I have 1000 daily visitors, each browsing 10 pages on average, wont there be a large number of records to `select` each time a personalized recommendation is required? The table will grow at 300K rows a month! It will take longer and longer to `select` the rows each time a search is made. *I guess the table for recording 'likes' will take the same table design*.

***Question 2:*** How do you bias the results of a search? For example, if a user as been searching for apple products, how does the search engine `realise` that the user likes apple products and subsequently bias the search towards them? Tag the pages and accumulate a record of tags on the page visited?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use a relational database for this type of thing, take a look at mongodb or cassandra. That's because you basically want to add a new column to the user's history so a column-oriented database makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

300k rows per month is not really that much, in fact, that's almost nothing. it doesn't matter if you use a relational or non-relational database for this.

Straightforward approach is the following:

1. put entries into the table/collection like this:

   timestamp, user, action, misc information

(make sure that you put as much information as possible, such that you don't need to join this data warehousing table with any other table)

1. partition by timestamp (one partition per month)
2. never go against this table directly, instead have say daily report jobs running over all data and collect and compute the necessary statistics and write them to a summary table.
3. reflect on your report queries and put appropriate partition local indexes
4. only go against the summary table from your web frontend

Comment: as for your second question, tagging of pages will only help in the simplest of cases. a better approach is to run an association rule mining algorithm (like frequent item sets / apriori) on your history table to figure out the dependencies between pages/users/etc... then bias the search result on the most important item sets (eg. where confidence and support are valid)

Comment: all these are new to me, can this be done in mysql? do you know of any tutorials on this?

Comment: it's not really difficult:

partitioning: what you want is range partitioning ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html )

indexing: a simple btree index (create index idxname on tablename(timestamp)). in mysql all indexes are partition local by default (unlike in oracle).

as for the report/mining jobs, you have two options, either scheduled jobs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html), or doing it outside of the database, i.e. retrieve the necessary rows and run the algorithm offline and put the results back in the database. depends on your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you stored only the last X results as opposed to everything, it would probably be do-able.  Might slow things down, but it'd work.  Any time you're writing more data and reading more data, there's going to be an impact.  Proper DBA methods such as indexing and query optimizing can help, but no matter what you use there's going to be an affect.

I'd personally look at storing just a default view for the user in a DB and use the session to keep track of the rest.  Sure, when you login there'd be no history.  But you could take advantage of that to highlight a set of special pages that you think are important or relevant to steer the user to.  A highlight system of sorts.  Faster, easier, and more user-friendly.

As for bias, you could write a set of keywords for each record and array sort them accordingly.  Wouldn't be terribly difficult using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I use MySQL and over 2M records (page views) a month and we run reports on that table daily and often.

The table is partitioned by month (like already suggested) and indexed where needed.

I also clear the table from data that is over 6 months by creating a new table called "page_view_YYMM" (YY=year, MM=month) and using some UNIONS when necessary

for the second question, the way I would approach it is by creating a table with the list of your products that is a simple:

```
url, description
```

the description will be a tag stripped of the content of your page or item (depend how you want to influence the search) and then add a full text index on description and a search on that table adding possible extra terms that you have been collecting while the user was surfing your site that you think are relevant (for example category name, or brand)